# Webpack production build with routing not load 1.bundle.js file

Tags: javascript, express, webpack, production, react-intl

I have a test repo for this problem ([Link](https://github.com/maxfarseer/routing-problem))

I think it's a problem with localization file. I use react-intl.

Dev version works good.

#### The problem is:

- create production build
- run production server
- open app http://localhost:3001/activities
- refresh page (works normal)
- click on *Link to id 1* (works normal)
- refresh page (not work, because **1.bundle.js** file not sent correctly, css too)

What is **1.bundle.js**? I think it is localization file. ([some info](https://monosnap.com/file/bTcLVZRfcbO6QDyAEkYBmJASwASgC0)). How I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in production config. I forgot publicPath setting.

```
...
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'production/public/'),
  filename: 'bundle.js',
  publicPath: '/' // this will make sure that all statics are hit at '/' route
},
...
```

Pull request [link](https://github.com/maxfarseer/routing-problem/pull/1/files)